# How is exposing the Google API key secure?

Tags: google-custom-search

I am new to Google Site Search and Google Custom Search and need to implement it on a large number of websites.  My concern, however, is that I will be paying $100+ a year, but my API key will be exposed in the JavaScript.  What prevents someone from just using my key or otherwise running up query hits and exhausting my quota?

Comment: I haven't used it.. but can you not specify your domain names that are accepted on the Google side of things? Pretty sure analytics works like that anyway. It prevents other sites using the key as the requests don't come from a valid domain

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Google this question? I'm certain they're the ones that your last paragraph addresses, as we're not Google and can't do anything about their policies. (If you find it "mildly infuriating", the place to complain is at Google.)

Comment: They even have steps to ensure you own a site that you want to use. [See here for information](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2402989?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=4513742)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I removed that paragraph.  My concern currently is that maybe I am just doing something wrong, or am ignorant about behind-the-scenes security on this product.  I was hoping the community here could shed some light on it.  Thanks again.